# How to get the application specific data folder (ProgramData)?

Tags: c#, winforms, appdata, programdata

I need to read and write files that contain application specific data, shared between all the users.

I tried to use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)`, but it returns only *C:\ProgramData*.

My question is :

Does it exist a system like `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.UserAppDataPath)`, which will give me the exact folder to write, according to my application name and version?

Or is *ProgramData* not the right place to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Have your tried?Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

Comment: Is the Windows namespace also available on WindowsForm - .Net 4.0?

Comment: Hmm, good question, but I don't think so, sorry.
But you should definetly find a path which matches your desires here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/370232/Where-should-I-store-my-data

Comment: Re-reading your question I might want to ask, why you not simply use the path to teh application itself?
It is a directory which should be available to all users. You could also use the built in c# Settigns files and use a specila Applciation settigns file. This even makes saving loading and restorign of settings very easy.

Comment: 1) Isn't ProgramFile a read-only directory?

2) The most of the data are stored inside a sqlite file, not a app.config (if it is you are talking about)

Comment: Now I know what your are talking about :)
Regarind a db file which is shared across multiple users I would use Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData as you already mentioned. It resolves to: C:\programdata + adding a subfolder specific to your application in form of a guid and/or company name.
I definately would use this approach!

Comment: Okay, so if there is no build-in function to get the "rigth" directory (I'm afraid of collision name), I will use Path.Combine :$

Comment: Afraid of collision names?
I don't see why there would be a collision, having the same directory twice is highely unusual, since the guid + company are most likely unique.
But whatever fits your needs!

Comment: c:\ProgramData does not permit write access, you'd need an installer that changes the user permissions to the subfolder.  Not a good idea, use AppData instead.  The "application specific folder" is just what you make it.  Boilerplate is company\product\version

Comment: @HansPassant Are you sure about that? [On my machine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pSsdx.png) `C:\ProgramData` has Write permission for the Users group to "This folder and subfolders" which means as a standard you should be able to create sub-folders in the Program Data folder.

Comment: Yes, quite sure.  Lots of bad installers hack it, forced by programmers that test with UAC off and didn't realize that "programdata" does not mean "program data".  I haven't been bitten by one yet, fingers crossed.

Answer (score 18):

I think CommonApplicationData is exactly what you're looking for, as it's the global folder for all applications which are not bound to a user.

```
var commonpath = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
var path = Path.Combine(commonpath, "YourAppName\\YourApp.exe");
try { 
    Process.Start(path);
    // or put data there or whatever
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(path);
}
```

There's also SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData for user-bound data.

Comment: For the newbs like me, GetFolderPath and SpecialFolder are in Environment, and Path is in System.IO

Answer (score 6):

> Does it exist a system like Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.UserAppDataPath), which will give me the exact folder to write, according to my application name and version?

No it doesn't exist, at least when running on Windows 7 (don't know about Windows 8/ WinRT/ Windows Store apps). Feasible solution is just to concat `Environment.GetFolderPath(...)` output with a custom path for your application. Typically, to reduce chances of clashing, that could be something like `YourOrganization\YourApplication`, or `YourFullName\YourApplication`, possibly also appending version.

> Or is ProgramData not the right place to do that.

That is the right place to store application-wide information on disk. Information related to your application and different for each Windows user logging on the machine should go instead in `<User folder>\AppData\Roaming\...`, or `<User folder>\AppData\Local\...`.

**Beware**: as somebody already mentioned in comments, normally one needs administrator rights in order to work inside *C:\ProgramData...*, hence you would need to prepare a setup project that, during install phase, would create the folder inside *ProgramData* and give the right permissions.